# Create an array from a loop in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

Here is my Matlab code:

```
Length = length(High);
i = 1;
j = 20;

while i < Length
     HighestHIGH(i) = max(High(i:j));
     i = i+1;
     j = j+1;
end
```

This gives an error at HighestHIGH line. What i am trying to accomplish is: Lets assume High is an array of length 100 (Length = 100). I want to get the highest numbers of in sets of 20 in new array. Ex:

```
HighestHIGH[1] = max(High(1:20));
HighestHIGH[2] = max(High(2:21));
HighestHIGH[3] = max(High(3:22));
...
HighestHIGH[80] = max(High(81:100));
```

Comment: "An" error is never enough. What kind of error? "Index exceeds matrix dimensions"? When `i==Length-1`, then j==Length+18` which exceeds the size of `High`.

Comment: [You could use `filter` to achieve the same in a single line of code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26013645/2732801)

Comment: @Daniel, how about adding that as an answer? It should definitely be done with that (even though the original question is "why doesn't this work?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `i==Length-1`, then `j==Length+18` which exceeds the size of `High`. The upper limit of your loop is too high.

I'd write this:

```
N=20;
HighestHIGH=zeros(length(High)-N+1);
for i=1:length(High)-N+1
   HighestHIGH(i) = max(High(i:i+N-1));
end
```

Note that with what you want, the final term is `HighestHIGH(81)=max(High(81:100))`.