# How do I take an n-day average of data in Matlab to match another time series?

Tags: matlab, datetime, time-series, match, average

I have daily time series data and I want to calculate 5-day averages of that data while also retrieving the corresponding start date for each of the 5-day averages. For example:

```
x = [732099 732100 732101 732102 732103 732104 732105 732106 732107 732108];
y=  [1 5 3 4 6 2 3 5 6 8];
```

Where x and y are actually size 92x1.

Firstly, how do I compute the 5-day mean when this time series data is not divisible by 5? Ultimately, I want to compute the 'jumping mean', where the average is not computed continuously (e.g., June 1-5, June 6-10, and so on).

I've tried doing the following:

```
Pentad_avg = mean(reshape(y(1:90),5,[]))'; %manually adjusted to be divisible by 5
Pentad_dt = x(1:5:90); %select every 5th day for time
```

However, `Pentad_dt` gives me dates `01-Jun-2004` and `06-Jun-2004` as output. And, that brings me to my second point.

I am looking to find 5-day averages for x and y that correspond to 5-day averages of another time series. This second time series has 5-day averaged data starting from 15-Jun-2004 until 29-Aug-2004 (instead of starting at 01-Jun-2004). Ultimately, how do I align the dates and 5-day averages between these two time series?

Comment: Not really clear why divisibility by five matters. Either way, check this out: http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/tsmovavg.html

Comment: I am interested in deriving a 5-day mean to smooth out some of the variability found in the daily time series data. @MadPhysicist

Comment: I got that part. My question and advice still stand.

Comment: The divisibility I can manually change. The more pressing question is the synchronization of the two time series in terms of time. Not sure if the financial function can apply to geophysical data here.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26003330/3798640, set N = 5

Comment: What do you expect to get in `Pentad_dt`? You asked for every 5th date, you got it. Seems like it worked.

Comment: I need the two time series dates to match, and I haven't been able to get them to match (for every 5th date).

Comment: Okay, I'm still working on the first part, trying to figure out what's wrong with the code you give. (And two questions in one is really kinda cheating.)

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization between two time series can be accomplished using the [timeseries object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/introduction.html#responsive_offcanvas).  Placing your data into an object allows Matlab to intelligently process it.  The most useful thing is adds for your usage is the [synchronize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.synchronize.html) method.

You'll want to make sure to properly set the time vector on each of the timeseries objects.

An example of what this might look like is as follows:

```
ts1 = timeseries(y,datestr(x));
ts2 = timeseries(OtherData,OtherTimes);
[ts1 ts2] = synchronize(ts1,ts2,'Uniform','Interval',5);
```

This should return to you each timeseries aligned to be with the same times.  You could also specify a specific time vector to align a timeseries to using the [resample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.resample.html) method.

Comment: This worked to find the 5-day interval, but how do I take the 5 day average of these synchronized time series?