# 100 point moving average filter on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, filter, moving-average

I need to create a 100 point moving average filter on MATLAB and then convolute it with data to make a graph. How am I supposed to make the filter and keep it at the same length as the data that I need to plot?

I need the filter to cover 686 data points.

Comment: 100 points or 686 points?

Comment: What have you tried so far? As written, this question currently lacks some specificity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing a moving average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002818/computing-a-moving-average)